# Django while running the server ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name'

Tags: django

Error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'book_store'
```

book_store is the project name

in manage.py the path for settings is

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'book_store.settings')
```

while runnung

```
python manage.py runserver
```

My folder hierarch

```
book_store
  static
  templates
  settings.py
  urls.py
  wsgi.py
  manage.py
```

Comment: Are you sure the virtual environment is up and running?

Comment: yes it running.

Comment: How did you create your project? What's your OS?

Comment: `manage.py` should be outside of `book_store` dir.

Comment: Its windows. django-admin startproject book_store

Comment: I don't use ```os.environ.setdefault``` in any of my Django projects and I'm on Windows too and just as @kamran890 mentioned ```manage.py``` is in the wrong folder. Delete everything, create and activate virtual environment and create your project again.

Comment: Got it. Thanks alot kamran890 and omid-shojaee